# Keyboard bindings from bash to zsh?

Tags: zsh, keyboard-shortcuts

I have the following entries on my `.inputrc` for bash:

```
"\C-p": history-search-backward
"\C-n": history-search-forward
"\e[A": history-search-backward
"\e[B": history-search-forward
"\e[C": forward-char
"\e[D": backward-char
"\ew": copy-region-as-kill
```

I just moved to `zsh`, and would like to keep the same keyboard bindings I have in bash. Do the lines above have an equivalent in `zsh`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Almost everything you can do in bash has a zsh equivalent, but you have to handle the translation on a case-by-case basis.

The line editor in zsh is [zle](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#Zsh-Line-Editor). The command to bind keys is [`bindkey`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#index-bindkey). The line edition commands that can be bound to keys are called [widgets](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#Standard-Widgets).

```
# You may want to call different history search commands, e.g.
# down-line-or-history or down-line-or-search (and up-*)
bindkey '^P' history-search-backward
bindkey '^N' history-search-forward
bindkey '\e[A' history-search-backward
bindkey '\e[B' history-search-forward
# The others should work already
```

Answer (score 2):

@Gilles answer helps you with the syntax in `.zshrc`

To find out what codes to use for each key, there is a helpful and complete list at http://zshwiki.org/home/zle/bindkeys. For me, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> then the key you want to know the code for works best (anywhere including inside nano or vim).

```
    bindkey "^[[5~" history-search-backward
    bindkey "^[[6~" history-search-forward
```